# The XslCompiledTransform output encoding

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dom, xslt

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace xslt_samples {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            XslCompiledTransform myXslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();

            // Here the myXslTransform.OutputSettings is null still...          
            myXslTransform.Load(@".\in3.xsl");

            // The myXslTransform.OutputSettings is not null now, but
            // I get an exception: the XmlWriterSettings.Encoding read only.
            myXslTransform.OutputSettings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            myXslTransform.Transform(@".\in.xml", @".\out.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is pointed it the comments.

How can I set the output encoding in this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
        XmlWriterSettings xws = myXslTransform.OutputSettings.Clone();
        xws.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create("out.xml", xws))
        {
          myXslTransform.Transform(@".\in.xml", xw);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is straight from [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.outputsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> ### XslCompiledTransform.OutputSettings Property
>
> Gets an `XmlWriterSettings` object that contains the output
>   information derived from the `xsl:output` element of the style sheet.
>
> #### Syntax
>
> `public XmlWriterSettings OutputSettings { get; }`

It's a read-only property.

The docs go on with

> #### Remarks
>
> This property is populated after a successful call to the `Load` method. It contains information derived from the `xsl:output` element of a compiled style sheet.
>
> This `XmlWriterSettings` object can be passed to the `XmlWriter.Create` method to create the `XmlWriter` object to which you want to output.

Conclusions:

- The `XmlWriter` accepts a custom `XmlWriterSettings` object.
- The `XslCompiledTransform` does not.